# IF Multiple Files Exist

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have an IF statement in a bash script that checks if six files exist or not.

**Bash Code**

```
if [ -f file1.txt ] && [ -f file2.txt ] && [ -f file3.txt ] && [ -f file4.txt ] && [ -f file5.txt ] && [ -f file6.txt ];
then
echo "Required Files Exist"
else
echo "Required Files Do Not Exist"
fi
```

**Expected Result**

```
Required Files Exist
```

**Actual Result**

```
Required Files Do Not Exist
```

All of the files DO exist

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why am I getting the `files do not exist` result instead of the `files exist` result?

Comment: does all files exists in the same directory?

Comment: In particular, do they all exist in the current working directory?

Comment: add `ls -l file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt file6.txt` after the second echo and see what it shows

Comment: I just run your script as `sh test.sh` and everything is working fine. I ran it as `./test.sh` and that went fine too. How do you run your script?

Comment: i ran the simple if statement and its working fine for me, how are you running this?

Comment: ls -l file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt file6.txt | grep "No such file or directory" then some file does not exist

Comment: @armagedescu Most implementations of `ls` will write that message to standard error, not standard output. `ls ... 2>&1 | grep ...` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run the script from a different directory.

For example: you are in `/root/` and run the script `/root/script/script.sh`

you will search files in `/root/`, but not in `/root/script/`.

Before run script try it: `touch file{1..6}.txt`

Comment: Running the script from the right directory would be better advice than littering the current directory with random empty files.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work fine if indeed all six files exist in the current directory.

You might want to refactor it to reduce code duplication, though.

```
all_exist () {
    local filename
    for filename; do
        test -f "$filename" && continue
        echo "$0: $filename does not exist - aborting" >&2
        return 1
    done
    return 0
}

all_exist file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt file6.txt && echo "$0: all files exist" >&2
```

If your files are really named this monotonously, perhaps just

```
all_exist file{1..6}.txt
```